# Dynamic Triple N Step

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

I am working on the problem from Cracking the Coding Interview:

A child is running up a staircase with n steps, and can hop either 1 step, 2 steps, or 3 steps at a time.
Implement a method to count how many possible ways the child can run up the stairs.
I came up with a dynamic solution:

```
def dynamic_prog(N):
    store_values = {1:1,2:2,3:3}
    return dynamic_prog_helper(N, store_values)

def dynamic_prog_helper(N, map_n):
    if N in map_n:
        return map_n[N]
    map_n[N] =  dynamic_prog_helper(N-1, map_n) + dynamic_prog_helper(N-2, map_n) + dynamic_prog_helper(N-3,map_n)
    return map_n[N]
```

I am not sure why it does not compute correctly.

```
dynamic_prog(5) = 11, but should be 13
dynamic_prog(4) =  6, but should be 7
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical problem is that your initial value for `store_values[3]` is wrong.  From 3 steps down, you have `4` possibilities:

3
   2 1
   1 2
   1 1 1

Fixing that error gets the expected results:

```
def dynamic_prog(N):
    store_values = {1:1,2:2,3:4}
    return dynamic_prog_helper(N, store_values)
...
for stair_count in range(3, 6):
    print dynamic_prog(stair_count)
```

Output:

```
4
7
13
```